# Sharepoint 2010 is changing my url in hyperlink column

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, hyperlink

I have a SharePoint 2010 web application "myapp.test.com" and I have extended this application to myapp-edit.test.com

I also have configured the following two alternative access mapping urls:

- myapp.test.com  (Zone: Default)
- myapp-edit.test.com (Zone: Intranet)

I have created a list with an hyperlink column.
The problem is that when I add an item  to this list with url: 
myapp.test.com/Pages/myPage.aspx then this url gets changed to myapp-edit.test.com/Pages/myPage.aspx

How do I make it stay as myapp.test.com/Pages/myPage.aspx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your URL address.

When you visit the server using: `myapp.test.com`, all urls will have `myapp.test.com` as a prefix.

The same thing applies to `myapp-edit.test.com`

Comment: I visit the server using myapp-edit.test.com Is it possible to change it? that link is not changed?

Comment: Kindly note that the href in your hyper link is '/Pages/myPage.aspx'


If you press F12 and select the hyperlink you will find it like:

<a href="/Pages/myPage.aspx">MyPage</a>

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that SharePoint adds the name of the server to the value in the Hyerlink column.

Say you entered: /test.com/Lists/xx/abc.com

SharePoint will convert this relative URL and add the server name as well. This value will become.

```
**http://myapp-edit**//test.com/Lists/xx/abc.com
```

For some people (including myself), its adding the internal name rather than the external one, and I suspect that is just because I am adding it from the internal zone.

The problem is that the link is not usable from the other zone. In your case, its the internal zone, and in my case and the case of [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3234afd8-ed28-40b0-bfd1-ec1ecf701f80/relative-urls-in-a-url-field-in-a-list) guy, its the external site that we can't access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes internally SharePoint does something. You can follow [this article](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/get-url-value-sharepoint-hyperlink-field-85.aspx) to Get URL value SharePoint hyperlink field. Hope this will be helpful. I already solved this issue. Provided you are using SharePoint 2010 object model.